# Get Popup Information With WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to visit URLs.  Certain URLs trigger popups which open in IE rather than in the WebBrowser.  I don't care much where they open.  But somehow finding out the URLs of the popups is the most important goal.  I keep seeing references to "NewWindow2" event on the web.  I'm not sure how related it is, but I don't know how to use it/where to find it, since WebBrowser does not have a NewWindow2 event, only a NewWindow event.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The Web_V1.NewWindow event works only to a degree.  Not all popups are being detected.  And some URLs only come up as "about:blank".  Ex. Use it on http://www.thedailybeast.com/. (Anybody know any other sites with notorious amounts of popups?)

Does anybody know a catch-all way to detect the resulting page of a WebBrowser popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a previously answered question that I believe will give you the solution. (Scroll down the code window for the C# version).

[System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser open links in same window or new window with same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175836/system-windows-forms-webbrowser-open-links-in-same-window-or-new-window-with-same)

Perhaps this project will help you with your goals to handle popups:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx#GoalBlock

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't see how I can use that code to find out the URL of the popups.  Once I add to the NewWindow event, where are the popups stored?

Comment: The URL should be in the string labeled "URL" in the event handler. In the example it was called "Web_V1_NewWindow"

Answer (score 4):

A good popup tester is http://www.popuptest.com.

The `WebBrowser` NewWindow event is in fact hooked on the underlying `NewWindow2` event. NewWindow works fine, but it does not give you the url where the new window is heading.

Since IE6, there is a [NewWindow3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768337%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) available, but this one is not exposed by the WebBrowser. However, here is a sample code that shows how to use it. In the `NewWindow3` event handler, you will see all popups and the corresponding url.

```
    // test code
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _events = new WebBrowserEvents(_wb); // register event sink, make sure ActiveXInsance is not null here

        _wb.Navigate("http://www.popuptest.com/");
    }

// this event sink declares the NewWindow3 event
public class WebBrowserEvents : StandardOleMarshalObject, DWebBrowserEvents2, IDisposable
{
    private AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie _cookie;

    public WebBrowserEvents(WebBrowser wb)
    {
        _cookie = new AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie(wb.ActiveXInstance, this, typeof(DWebBrowserEvents2));
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.StatusTextChange(string text)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("StatusTextChange text:" + text);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.ProgressChange(int progress, int progressMax)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("ProgressChange progress:" + progress + " progress:" + progressMax);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.CommandStateChange(int command, bool enable)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("CommandStateChange command:" + command + " enable:" + enable);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.DownloadBegin()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("DownloadBegin");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.DownloadComplete()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("DownloadComplete");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.TitleChange(string text)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("TitleChange text:" + text);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.PropertyChange(string szProperty)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("PropertyChange szProperty:" + szProperty);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object flags, ref object targetFrameName, ref object postData, ref object headers, ref bool cancel)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("BeforeNavigate2 URL:" + URL);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.NewWindow2(ref object pDisp, ref bool cancel)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("NewWindow2");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.NavigateComplete2(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("NavigateComplete2 URL:" + URL);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("DocumentComplete URL:" + URL);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnQuit()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnQuit");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnVisible(bool visible)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnVisible visible:" + visible);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnToolBar(bool toolBar)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnToolBar toolBar:" + toolBar);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnMenuBar(bool menuBar)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnMenuBar menuBar:" + menuBar);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnStatusBar(bool statusBar)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnStatusBar statusBar:" + statusBar);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnFullScreen(bool fullScreen)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnFullScreen fullScreen:" + fullScreen);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.OnTheaterMode(bool theaterMode)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("OnTheaterMode theaterMode:" + theaterMode);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.WindowSetResizable(bool resizable)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("WindowSetResizable resizable:" + resizable);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.WindowSetLeft(int left)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("WindowSetLeft left:" + left);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.WindowSetTop(int top)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("WindowSetTop top:" + top);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.WindowSetWidth(int width)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("WindowSetWidth width:" + width);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.WindowSetHeight(int height)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("WindowSetHeight height:" + height);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.WindowClosing(bool isChildWindow, ref bool cancel)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("WindowClosing isChildWindow:" + isChildWindow);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.ClientToHostWindow(ref int cx, ref int cy)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("ClientToHostWindow cx:" + cx + " cy:" + cy);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.SetSecureLockIcon(int secureLockIcon)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("SetSecureLockIcon secureLockIcon:" + secureLockIcon);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.FileDownload(ref bool cancel)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("FileDownload");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object frame, ref object statusCode, ref bool cancel)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("NavigateError url:" + URL);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.PrintTemplateInstantiation(object pDisp)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("PrintTemplateInstantiation");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.PrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("PrintTemplateTeardown");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.UpdatePageStatus(object pDisp, ref object nPage, ref object fDone)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("UpdatePageStatus");
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.PrivacyImpactedStateChange(bool bImpacted)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("PrivacyImpactedStateChange bImpacted:" + bImpacted);
    }

    void DWebBrowserEvents2.NewWindow3(ref object pDisp, ref bool cancel, int dwFlags, ref object bstrUrlContext, ref object bstrUrl)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("NewWindow3 bstrUrlContext:" + bstrUrlContext + " bstrUrl:" + bstrUrl);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_cookie != null)
        {
            _cookie.Disconnect();
            _cookie = null;
        }
    }
}

[ComImport, Guid("34A715A0-6587-11D0-924A-0020AFC7AC4D"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
internal interface DWebBrowserEvents2
{
    [DispId(0x66)]
    void StatusTextChange([In] string text);
    [DispId(0x6c)]
    void ProgressChange([In] int progress, [In] int progressMax);
    [DispId(0x69)]
    void CommandStateChange([In] int command, [In] bool enable);
    [DispId(0x6a)]
    void DownloadBegin();
    [DispId(0x68)]
    void DownloadComplete();
    [DispId(0x71)]
    void TitleChange([In] string text);
    [DispId(0x70)]
    void PropertyChange([In] string szProperty);
    [DispId(250)]
    void BeforeNavigate2([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp, [In] ref object URL, [In] ref object flags, [In] ref object targetFrameName, [In] ref object postData, [In] ref object headers, [In, Out] ref bool cancel);
    [DispId(0xfb)]
    void NewWindow2([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] ref object pDisp, [In, Out] ref bool cancel);
    [DispId(0xfc)]
    void NavigateComplete2([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp, [In] ref object URL);
    [DispId(0x103)]
    void DocumentComplete([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp, [In] ref object URL);
    [DispId(0xfd)]
    void OnQuit();
    [DispId(0xfe)]
    void OnVisible([In] bool visible);
    [DispId(0xff)]
    void OnToolBar([In] bool toolBar);
    [DispId(0x100)]
    void OnMenuBar([In] bool menuBar);
    [DispId(0x101)]
    void OnStatusBar([In] bool statusBar);
    [DispId(0x102)]
    void OnFullScreen([In] bool fullScreen);
    [DispId(260)]
    void OnTheaterMode([In] bool theaterMode);
    [DispId(0x106)]
    void WindowSetResizable([In] bool resizable);
    [DispId(0x108)]
    void WindowSetLeft([In] int left);
    [DispId(0x109)]
    void WindowSetTop([In] int top);
    [DispId(0x10a)]
    void WindowSetWidth([In] int width);
    [DispId(0x10b)]
    void WindowSetHeight([In] int height);
    [DispId(0x107)]
    void WindowClosing([In] bool isChildWindow, [In, Out] ref bool cancel);
    [DispId(0x10c)]
    void ClientToHostWindow([In, Out] ref int cx, [In, Out] ref int cy);
    [DispId(0x10d)]
    void SetSecureLockIcon([In] int secureLockIcon);
    [DispId(270)]
    void FileDownload([In, Out] ref bool cancel);
    [DispId(0x10f)]
    void NavigateError([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp, [In] ref object URL, [In] ref object frame, [In] ref object statusCode, [In, Out] ref bool cancel);
    [DispId(0xe1)]
    void PrintTemplateInstantiation([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp);
    [DispId(0xe2)]
    void PrintTemplateTeardown([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp);
    [DispId(0xe3)]
    void UpdatePageStatus([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp, [In] ref object nPage, [In] ref object fDone);
    [DispId(0x110)]
    void PrivacyImpactedStateChange([In] bool bImpacted);
    [DispId(0x111)]
    void NewWindow3([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] ref object pDisp, [In, Out] ref bool cancel, [In] int dwFlags, [In] ref object bstrUrlContext, [In] ref object bstrUrl);
}
```

Comment: My sincere apologies for resurrecting an ancient thread and answer, but I need to use your solution above - although some events seem to fire, WindowSetHeight and similar don't - do you happen to know why this might be?  I'm using IE11 and .NET 4.6.2

Comment: @lukep - no I don't, but look at remarks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768302(v=vs.85)#remarks it's only raised when setting Height, not when height changes in general otherwise ask another question.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

```
webBrowser1.Navigating += (sndr, ee) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(ee.Url.DnsSafeHost + "\n" + ee.Url.ToString());
};

webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.thedailybeast.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

the wrapper from the .NET framework does NOT expose all capabilities of the underlying native webbrowser control...

For that you would have to wrap that control yourself - a rather tedious task which has already been care of thankfully... for full source code and details see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

This "complete wrapper" contains for example `NewWindow2` which you mentioned above...

Another option would be to use chrome via http://awesomium.com/ which supports even a window-less mode and is thus ideal for doing all kinds of browser stuff programatically...

Comment: Why do I need the new wrapper control if .NET already provides NewWindow2 handling?  Would the popups that are currently not triggering the NewWindow event be caught by that wrapper?

Comment: that wrapper is MUCH MORE COMPLETE than the .NET built-in wrapper... so short of some 0day-exploit of IE this would allow you to do whatever the IE control from MS allows native code to do (which is much much more than the .NET wrapper!)... just follow the link... the author describes the differences rather detailed...

Comment: NewWindow2 is already handled by the WebBrowser control and raises the NewWindow .NET event. There are many things that can be tweaked with the standard WebBrowser control without re-implementing the whole stuff.