# Open New Window In Current Web Browser Control With Submitted Data

Tags: vb.net, post, webbrowser-control, shdocvw

In my Project, i am using a web browser control. I also able to handle new window in same browser control using the help from follow so answer:

[SO Answer To Open New Window In Same Webbrowser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175836/system-windows-forms-webbrowser-open-links-in-same-window-or-new-window-with-same)

But the issue i am facing is, if i submit a form that open in new window that don't work.

I have noticed that SHDocVw Newwindow event has PostData (as Object) parameter but webbrowser control need PostData as bytearray.

SHDocVw Newwindow event parameters:

```
(URL As String, Flags As Integer, TargetFrameName As String, ByRef PostData As Object, Headers As String, ByRef Processed As Boolean)
```

Webbrowser control navigate parameters:

```
(string source, string targetFrameName, byte[] postData, string additionalHeaders);
```

As Asked Here is My Code: (But as it is same as the mentioned SO answer, I  don't think it would be any help)

```
Private Sub Web_V1_NewWindow(URL As String, Flags As Integer, TargetFrameName As String, ByRef PostData As Object, Headers As String, ByRef Processed As Boolean) Handles Web_V1.NewWindow
        Processed = True
        webMain.Navigate(URL)
End Sub
```

So, my question is how can i convert that postdata object to bytearray so that webbrowser control can handle the submitted form/data correctly?

Comment: Please update with what you have tried so we can better assist you. It would also help if you could provide an example for us so we can replicate and help you find the issue.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, sir, that linked so answer page has all. i just tired that. as i can't use post data and don't know how to convert object to byte array. i didn't try any further than that.